# Gem Permission Error When installing fluentd plugin

Tags: ruby, docker, jenkins, rubygems, fluentd

When running docker on Jenkins i am getting the following error:

```
While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0 directory.
[0m[91m /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:712:in `verify_gem_home'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:902:in `pre_install_checks'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:302:in `install'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:104:in `install'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:194:in `block in install'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:182:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:182:in `install'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:210:in `install_gem'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:226:in `block in install_gems'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:219:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:219:in `install_gems'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:167:in `execute'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/command.rb:323:in `invoke_with_build_args'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:185:in `process_args'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:149:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
    /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

I've seen forums suggest that it is the alpine version 3.14 > used in fluentd image. This image uses alpine 3.16 and the docker version is 20.10.22 so it is the very latest one. This works locally with no issues and same docker version. I have also checked which user it is running as and directory permissions both which are root and have wrx on the user level.
Docker file is below:

```
FROM fluent/fluentd:v1.14.6-1.1
USER root
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    ca-certificates

COPY cert.cer /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates

RUN apk add --update --virtual .build-deps \
        build-base ruby-dev
RUN apk add --update mariadb-dev

COPY cert.cer /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ssl_certs/cert.cer
RUN gem install  fluent-plugin-sql --no-document
RUN gem install  mysql2
RUN gem install  bigdecimal
RUN gem install elasticsearch -v 7.17.0
RUN gem install  --minimal-deps fluent-plugin-elasticsearch
RUN gem source --clear-all
RUN apk del .build-deps
USER fluent
```

I've tried changing the directory permissions and removing sudo altogether and no luck. Changing to other docker versions has no luck either.

Comment: Is some specific gem causing this error? Is there anything in the error logs?

Comment: Can you add more info what is the docker run command you're using in Jenkins vs Locally?

Comment: When you say you changed directory permissions, do you mean just the 3.1.0 directory or the whole path? Maybe try with whole path.